# How do I redirect after executing PHP action and return a value (and force a browser redirect if possible)?

Tags: php

Please I created a form with an action page. That retrieves a value from MySQL database column.

The form submits quite alright and the data is retrieved, too. But the problem is the header('Location: home.php'); has refused to redirect the user back home after the information has been retrieved. Plus, the user needs to refresh the browser before they see the retrieved data so I don't know it is possible to do the following:

1. Redirect to the homepage after the action has been executed,
2. return the value (which is stored in a variable) back to the homepage.

By the way, this is the PHP action page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include(cafedbconfig.php);

$cafeconnection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpass', 'dbname');
$query = "SELECT name, email, password, balance FROM cafeusers WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($cafeconnection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($MyConn));
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $balance = (int) stripslashes($row["balance"]);
    $email = $row["email"];
    $name = $row["username"];
    $cafepass = $row["password"];


    
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

    if(isset($_POST['cafepass'])){
        $pass = $_POST['cafepass'];
        $newbalance1 = $balance - 50;
               
        $select = "UPDATE cafeusers SET balance = '$newbalance1' WHERE username='$name' AND password='$pass'";
}
        if (mysqli_query($cafeconnection, $select)) {
  $returnvalue = "VIP 1 Upgraded successfully!";
} else {
  $returnvalue = "Error" . mysqli_error($cafeconnection);
}
mysqli_close($cafeconnection);
    return $returnvalue;
    header ('Location: home.php');
?>
```

I want to redirect to home.php after this action has been executed and then return with $returnvalue back to home.php because I intend to use the said variable.

if possible, force a browser refresh after doing so. I'd really appreciate the help. Cheers.

Comment: Is this academic code purely for learning, or is it intended for a production site with actual users?

Comment: Note: `stripslashes` has absolutely no place in production code.

Comment: @tadman It is academic. It's a school project.

Comment: You should learn about using placeholder values as it not only makes your code easier to read, it avoids entire classes of bugs and saves a ton of time you'd otherwise spend debugging. You should also at least dabble with how password hashing and [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) works.

Comment: Note: You don't "return the value ... back to the homepage" you *render a new page*. Remember, HTTP is largely based on request/response. Your client (browser) makes a request, your server (PHP) sends a full response, typically rendered as a page. Unless you're using AJAX or a front-end like React/Vue, this is how it will always work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So there is a way to redirect back to the page from where the form was submitted? Also, is there a way I can do with AJAX too (or any means possible) please? thanks.

Comment: There are patterns for doing this, but the easiest is to just redirect back with a `Location` header which reloads the previous page, fetching new data.

Comment: In order to carry some message from one page to another you can use a session. Note that in case of error, there **must be no redirect**, as it is dictated by HTTP standard. So the only message you got to carry is "updated successfully"

Answer (score -1):

Try closing the database connection after your script has completed.

// ....some PHP code...

mysqli_close($cafeconnection);

?>